# calling Asynchronous ActionResult Methods in MVC using javascript loop not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, actionresult

My MVC page is rendering multiple partial views using javascript. the problem start when i try to use Async actionResult because some partial views take time to finish while calling API.
So i tried to convert the ActionResult of the partial view to be Async ,and call it using Ajax, expecting to execute all partial views at same time, but when testing the code i found that rendering partial views is synchronous and if one partial view take time then other request are blocked until it finish.

the picture should make it clear... is what im doing is correct? why it's not working Asynchronous?
[code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm9YM.jpg)

As you can see, rendering the first partial view for zone 7 will take 10 sec, and all other requests are pending until it finish.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Session in your application? If so try disabling it: `<sessionState mode="Off" />` and check the results again. You might get some nice results this time :-)

Comment: why you using Task.Delay ? Also if you are passing any array then instead of looping you should pass all data in array then send it to controller

Comment: other requests are not pending. As can be seen in diagram, all requests are initiated parallelly. Just that, all requests other than zone_7 are taking more time. To confirm, remove zone_7 item from the request array and check.

Comment: @Yashveer  i'm using it just to simplify the case, although using Task.Delay shouldn't cause the problem. each request in the normal case will call different controller.

Comment: @Sridhar all requests take less than second to be done, but as you can see all request are pending until the request with zone7 is done, while the controller should receive and process all request in parallel and zone7 request should not affect other request to wit 10 seconds

Comment: @Darin  i will try that, but i need to use the session for sure, i can't disable it. so do you mean that i can't use Async while session is enabled?